# (.Net + SQL Server +Azure )  vs   (Java + Oracle +Google App Engine) which is better for this project specifically?

Tags: java, .net, asp.net, sql

I have to develop an ERP System for a 2,000+ end users organisation.

Could you please suggest me with comparable points that among (Java or .Net)
in which technology I should invest money and time? Although I have done 
some average projects in both, but this project is going  to be very big in near
future in terms of scalability.

I want to know your experiences and some tips from you people, so that I can  develop
and deploy this project efficiently.

I rate .Net > Java for this project only due to less development  time available.
We have to use some Rapid App Development technology.

I have to deploy this on Cloud (Azure or Google App engine).
It will be better if I got answers from those people who works in both (.Net and Java).

I will appreciate answers from your experiences.

Comment: When you accept an answer you will most likely not get more answers.

Comment: I don't really have an answer, but I've been trying to make similar decisions and posted my thoughts on my blog. You might find some of it useful, and I'm interested to hear other opinions (I'm still undecided!)

http://blog.dantup.com/2010/10/google-app-engine-gae-vs-amazon-elastic-computing-ec2-vs-microsoft-azure
http://blog.dantup.com/2009/12/microsoft-windows-azure-vs-google-app.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest creating a very small proof-of-concept project in both technologies, which do something real - like allow people to log in, see messages, and allow them to type in new messages, and log out again.

Even if the project is laughably small, if you do it well, you will have a finished product on each platform which have shown you by experience how things works and if you like the way you had to do them.   You will be able to see if you can debug in the cloud, if you can profile when load testing, if you can do fast work inhouse which then works well when deployed to the cloud.

And you will need to figure out things.  Are the online resources good?  How responsive is the StackOverflow community for each platform when you ask questions?

Personally, I consider the ".NET is Windows-only" to be important.  Except for that I do not believe there is any technical showstopper for either platform.

Comment: I think we can go with .net as far as RAD is concerned.

Answer (score 2):

I think both approaches can be used to deliver this successfully.  I would expect you to have the same amount of success/pain with either choice.  When it comes to making a decision you should base it on the amount of expertise that you have to hand.  That is, your own and that of your existing colleagues and the resources that you can acquire (new recruits, contractors, consultants etc.).

That said a couple of technical notes:

- The Java approach tends to have more freedom, i.e. more frameworks and choice of technologies for various solutions (although GAE will bring in some restrictions).
- There is less choice in the .NET space, but that is not always a bad thing.  E.g. you tend not end up in tireless debates about the logging frameworks.
- Java is starting to age as a language and C# is a bit nicer, however there a number of newer languages that run on the Java VM (Scala, Groovy, Ruby, Clojure).

Comment: can u please suggest me which will costs less (an overview only) , in terms of manpower, time , quality .

Comment: I think you've missed the point of my answer.  The technology doesn't matter that much when making this type of decision.  The expertise that you have available to you is a much bigger factor.  With 2 equally skilled teams in each technology, I would bet that cost (time, resources, etc.) would be roughly the same.